# HAProxy - run lua script based on remote agent-check

Tags: nginx, lua, load-balancing, haproxy

We have an haproxy load-balancer that forwards traffic to our backend servers. Sometimes those servers cannot handle the traffic amount and we want to send an 204 status code response instead of a 500 status code. I wrote a lua script that does so and want to find the way to serve that script in case our servers cannot handle all the traffic.
The agent check runs as a pod in k8s and sends us back the weight of traffic we should forward as 204. Currently what we do is forward the request to another server( so called dummy nginx) who's all purpose is to just send that 204 status code back to the client, we want to skip this server and send the status code directly from the haproxy server.
How do i make my haproxy.cfg redirect to the lua script in case of the scaler sending a weight higher than 0% ?

my lua script:

```
# 204.lua
core.register_service("204-response", "http", function(applet)
local response = ""
applet:set_status(204)
applet:add_header("Content-Length", "0")
applet:start_response()
applet:send(response)
end)
```

my current haproxy.cfg

```
backend some-backend
server dummy-nginx dummy-nginx weight 100 check maxqueue 1 maxconn 20000 slowstart 180s agent-check agent-inter 15s agent-addr k8s-service-addr agent-port 9999
```